# Создание модели данных для БД

Tags: база-данных, моделирование

Появились сложности с созданием модели данных, ранее ничего сложнее модели данных, типа продажи не делал.
У меня есть сущность "сделка", у нее есть номер(идентификатор) и набор атрибутов(тип, дата и т.д.)
Вопрос - сделка имеет набор динамических признаков (допустим "сделка выполнена", или не состоялась, или входит в массив сделок для аудита и пр.) таких признаков около 10, причем у некоторых нужно отслеживать историю изменения признаков, как лучше реализовать данный момент? В одну сущность тонну полей напихать, или лучше сделать множество сущностней (например "сделки для аудита") и просто добавлять туда по необходимости? 
Мой мизерный опыт проектирования баз данных подсказывает, что второй вариант лучше.

Comment: "выполнена" и не "состоялась" это похоже на один и тот же признак, "статус". Среди этих 10 признаков большинство могут быть вне зависимости от других ?

Comment: да, так и есть, я просто не правильно этот признак обозначил.

Comment: для примера несколько признаков:
статус сделки
статус аудита(назначен, проведен успешно)
есть фиксированные массивы(пулы) сделок(3 шт), отобранные по определенному признакам собственно нужно 3 поля наличия в том или ином пуле(сделка может входить сразу в 3)

Comment: "Среди этих 10 признаков большинство могут быть вне зависимости от других ?"
Да, эти 10 признаков - независимые.

Comment: Ну пулы однозначно в отдельную таблицу id-сделки, id-пула. Статус пока полем напрашивается. Там где с "историей изменений", там вообще разговор особый. Если просто показать где то историю, но в большинстве мест используется только текущее значение, то возможно значение может быть полем, а история храниться сама по себе. Если же эта история где то используется более подробно, например делается выборка данных по состоянию на определенный момент, то тогда возможно стоит вынести поле в отдельную таблицу с датой начала (или интервалом действия)

Comment: спасибо, очень помогли, особенно с историей изменений.